# Imitating UICollectionView image preview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCell created in storyboard. I customized cell by adding to it UIImage. After user taps cell I want to show image from particular cell increased by size. To implement that I added UIImageView to view, situated it on top and made:
`[previewImage setAlpha:0];` and `[previewImage setHidden:YES];` in `-viewDidLoad`. At `-didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` I want to set value of image in this UIImageView to the appropriate in touched cell. I tried

`previewImage.image = [(CustomCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] image].image;`

but it don't works. In logs I see that `previewImage.image` returns null. So how can I retrieve image value from cell in right way?

Comment: you add images from array??

Comment: yes, from NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `previewImage.image` this way:

`UIImage *preImage = [(CustomCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] image].image;
    [previewView setImage:preImage];`

Answer (score 0):

hey here you just use the bellow delegate method of `UICollectionView`

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // TODO: Select Item
    
}
```

For More info see this [UICollectionview-example](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uicollectionview-example)

i hope this help you..